# SOAP fault handling in java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am pretty new to SOAP and I am trying to understand SOAP fault handling (in Java).  I have done reading about this topic but there are still some concepts that remain unclear to me.

More specifically, how to handle various response codes using Eclipse WSDL editor. I have used Eclipse WSDL editor to create my WSDL but I am open to using another tool such as SoapUI to accomplish this (handling faults).

I've attached an image of a simple web service that is supposed to take UserID (request) and return information about the user such as name, age etc (response). I would like to handle warning and error codes that may be returned by the response. E.g. duplicate UserID found > code "ABC" or no UserID found > code "XYZ".

I don't really understand how/where these codes are returned and where to process them. Would the response just return "ABC" as a String?

[image]

The following question is based on the attached image.
Do I need to setup displayUserInfoFault as a new class that extends the Exception class and add "throws displayUserInfoFault" to the displayUserInfo() method?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Salman - Thanks for your reply. Your explanation answers my question. Please, post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I am glade that it help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a proper response to the caller. Then you need to return an object not only one fields. For example you can create new class you can call it `Response` that contains the fields you want to display it to the caller like `responCode` and `responseDescription`. Using these two fields you can cover the different error cases you have. And of course you need to change the return type of the method `playUserInfo` to be of type `Response`